# Do not preventDefault when a key is pressed

Tags: javascript, events, dom

I'm using `window.history` and intercepting link clicks:

```
document.querySelector('a[data-history]').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  // window.history stuff
})
```

The problem now is that if I want to open the link in a new tab instead, it doesn't work. That is, the Javascript disables opening the link in a new tab and just does the same `window.history` code. Specifically, this is when you hold down COMMAND + CLICK on Mac. What is the best way to not preventDefault when a key is pressed?

Comment: This post might help you (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false).

Comment: Set up an event handler for when you press the Ctrl/Command keys, then don't execute the above statement when you hit that event.

Comment: I know how to use eventPropagation and I'm not using jQuery

Comment: is there a way to detect if a key is currently pressed without listening for events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `event.ctrlKey`, `shiftKey`, `altKey`, `metaKey`